# copy lines with same word count for a line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file which should contain 14 words per line separated by a delimiter ",". But my incoming files have 16, 19 and unordered count of words. Now I need to copy those lines with word count 14 per line to a new file. How do I do it in linux?

I have tried many commands looking in our forum but I am not able to figure out.

`awk -F ',' '{printf NF -1, NR}' ouput` is also not working while trying to count.I am new to linux scripting, please suggest on how to move these lines with word count 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F, 'NF==14' input.txt > output.txt
```